# Sencha ExtJS: radiofields unselected

Tags: extjs

Please consider two modal windows that refer to the common container with the group of `radiofield` in the below fiddle.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3e45

Initially, the first radio R1 is correctly checked in containers of both windows. However, checking any `radiofield` on one of the windows unselects all the `radiofield` items on another window.

Two windows contain independent instances of the container, so it's unclear how they can affect each other. This behavior is not happening with any other elements (e.g. checkboxes), only radios.

Any ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the same 'name' for the radios.. If I append the distinct suffixes to the name in two windows, it starts working.. But feels like an ugly workaround...

Answer (score 0):

Put/wrap your radio fieldset in form panel, in this case it will keep the value (yourForm.getValues()):

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('fsContainerHandler', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.fsContainerHandler'
        });

        Ext.define('fsContainer', {
            extend: 'Ext.form.Panel', // ---== Extending form now. ==---
            xtype: 'xFSContainer',
            sfx: '',
            controller: 'fsContainerHandler',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'myFieldset',
                reference: 'fsRef',
                flex: 1,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    checked: true,
                    name: 'myRadio',
                    boxLabel: 'R1'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    checked: false,
                    name: 'myRadio',
                    boxLabel: 'R2'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    checked: false,
                    name: 'myRadio',
                    boxLabel: 'R3'
                }]
            }]
        });

        Ext.define('mainContainerHandler', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.mainContainerHandler',
            singleton: true,
            onButton1Click: function () {
                var win = this.getView().window1;
                win.show();
            },
            onButton2Click: function () {
                var win = this.getView().window2;
                win.show();
            }
        });

        Ext.define('mainContainer', {
            extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            controller: 'mainContainerHandler',
            window1: null,
            window2: null,
            initComponent: function () {
                this.window1 = Ext.create('window1');
                this.window2 = Ext.create('window2');
                this.callParent(arguments);
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Window 1',
                reference: 'btn1',
                handler: mainContainerHandler.onButton1Click,
                scope: mainContainerHandler
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Window 2',
                reference: 'btn2',
                handler: mainContainerHandler.onButton2Click,
                scope: mainContainerHandler
            }]
        });

        Ext.define('window1', {
            extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
            title: 'Window1',
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            referenceHolder: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'xFSContainer',
                reference: 'theContainer'
            }]
        });

        Ext.define('window2', {
            extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
            title: 'Window2',
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            referenceHolder: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'xFSContainer',
                reference: 'theContainer'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('mainContainer', {
            renderTo: document.body
        });
    }
});
```